# PM2 inside bash script deployed by puppet not working

Tags: shell-script, node.js, puppet

```
#!/bin/bash

# install needed RPMS
yum -y install gcc-c++ git

# downlaod and compile node
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
tar -xvzf  node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
cd node-v0.12.7
./configure
make
sudo make install

# install pm2 via npm
/usr/local/bin/npm install pm2 -g

# start processes.json
cd /home/admin/Order-Management/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start processes.json
```

The above script run perfectly when I run it locally but when I try to execute it with puppet on the client machine the last line throwing the following error.

```
    /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I am using RedHat 6 master and RedHat 6 client. I saw a solution here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281057/node-forever-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-director However it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably node is not in your PATH during execution with puppet. Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# install needed RPMS
yum -y install gcc-c++ git

# downlaod and compile node
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
tar -xvzf  node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
cd node-v0.12.7
./configure
make
sudo make install

# install pm2 via npm
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm install pm2 -g

# start processes.json
cd /home/admin/Order-Management/
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start processes.json
```